# Why is my Android NFC scanner not working

Tags: android, nfc

I have read many posts related to NFC scanning on Android, however I am unable to make it work.
The onNewIntent function never gets fired by my app sample.

In my activity, I have the following code:

```
//The array lists to hold our messages
private ArrayList<String> messagesToSendArray = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> messagesReceivedArray = new ArrayList<>();

//Text boxes to add and display our messages
private EditText txtBoxAddMessage;
private TextView txtReceivedMessages;
private TextView txtMessagesToSend;

private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

public void addMessage(View view) {
    String newMessage = txtBoxAddMessage.getText().toString();
    messagesToSendArray.add(newMessage);

    txtBoxAddMessage.setText(null);
    updateTextViews();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Added Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


private  void updateTextViews() {
    txtMessagesToSend.setText("Messages To Send:\n");
    //Populate Our list of messages we want to send
    if(messagesToSendArray.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messagesToSendArray.size(); i++) {
            txtMessagesToSend.append(messagesToSendArray.get(i));
            txtMessagesToSend.append("\n");
        }
    }

    txtReceivedMessages.setText("Messages Received:\n");
    //Populate our list of messages we have received
    if (messagesReceivedArray.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messagesReceivedArray.size(); i++) {
            txtReceivedMessages.append(messagesReceivedArray.get(i));
            txtReceivedMessages.append("\n");
        }
    }
}

//Save our Array Lists of Messages for if the user navigates away
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("messagesToSend", messagesToSendArray);
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("lastMessagesReceived",messagesReceivedArray);
}

//Load our Array Lists of Messages for when the user navigates back
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    messagesToSendArray = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("messagesToSend");
    messagesReceivedArray = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("lastMessagesReceived");
}



private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtBoxAddMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBoxAddMessage);
    txtMessagesToSend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessageToSend);
    txtReceivedMessages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessagesReceived);
    Button btnAddMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddMessage);

    btnAddMessage.setText("Add Message");
    updateTextViews();

    //Check if NFC is available on device
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(mNfcAdapter != null) {
        //Handle some NFC initialization here
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC not available on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    //Check if NFC is available on device
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(mNfcAdapter != null) {
        //This will refer back to createNdefMessage for what it will send
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);

        //This will be called if the message is sent successfully
        mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
    }


    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);


    this.onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
}

@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent nfcEvent) {
    //This will be called when another NFC capable device is detected.
    if (messagesToSendArray.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    //We'll write the createRecords() method in just a moment
    NdefRecord[] recordsToAttach = createRecords();
    //When creating an NdefMessage we need to provide an NdefRecord[]
    return new NdefMessage(recordsToAttach);
}

@Override
public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent nfcEvent) {
    //This is called when the system detects that our NdefMessage was
    //Successfully sent.
    messagesToSendArray.clear();
}

public NdefRecord[] createRecords() {
    NdefRecord[] records = new NdefRecord[messagesToSendArray.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < messagesToSendArray.size(); i++){

        byte[] payload = messagesToSendArray.get(i).
                getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(
                NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  //Our 3-bit Type name format
                NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,        //Description of our payload
                new byte[0],                //The optional id for our Record
                payload);                   //Our payload for the Record

        records[i] = record;
    }
    return records;
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("TAG", "onNewIntent: "+intent.getAction());
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name="com.banalapps.nfcmesssenger.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am aware that this is probably a duplicate, but any help would be greatly appreciated as I struggled for days trying to make this work.

Comment: What version of Android are you running this on?

Comment: I am running this code on Android 9.0.

Comment: OK, so not because Android Beam and the API's like `setNdefPushMessageCallback` are deprecated and removed from Android 10

Comment: Ok thank you for helping. Then I guess there is a better way to do it if I want to support android 6 to android 10 for example ?

Comment: Googles reason for removing it was that there are better method to send data between devices and the Bluetooth/Wifi Direct should be used instead. Going forward NFC is for only reading and writing to NFC cards and Host Card Emulation. It is possible but very complicated to use Host Card emulation on Android to send Data between two devices still (One pretends to be a NFC card and the other just reads it as if it was a NFC card)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the topic. The thing is that I want my app to be able to exchange data with close devices without the need of pairing them. So bluetooth is not an option for me, do you think that I can achieve this with wifi direct?

Comment: I believe that it is possible to send data with bluetooth without pairing and googles files app shows sharing of files via wifi direct.

Comment: Ok I will try to implement it with wifi direct. Thank you Andrew, and have a nice day :)